# How can I reset and generate sources.list

Tags: 22.04, ppa

I removed my /etc/apt/sources.list file by mistake. How can I generate it again?

Best regards

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: `sudo apt update -y` output is: E: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
linux@dell:~$

Comment: why these appears

Comment: Look at the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` ... If any results are returned then that could be resulting from one of those ... rename those to any extension other than `.list` e.g. `somefile.list.disabled` and try again ... and you don't need `-y` with `update` as it's useless here.

Comment: Done without any errors. Thanks again